# Submit uses "view-source code" but not my ajax updated code

Tags: jquery, submit

I want to submit a form with checkboxes (and the data of the checkboxes is after user input updated by ajax (checked/nonchecked))and the submit uses the post method.

And when the form is submitted, I retrieved only the old data (before the ajax update) and not the updated data(after the ajax update). I have checked my source code after the ajax call. But the code hasn't change. And when I check the javascript console in Chrome, the code is changed.

I have already read a bit on the internet about the problem and I know that it is something with the DOM, but I'm not so familiar with that.

Oh before I forgot. I used JQuery.ajax for the ajax-call.

Can somebody help me with my problem?

Grtz,

Arne

PS: sorry for my bad english

Comment: https://addons.mozilla.org/id/firefox/addon/view-source-chart/?src=search see this article : http://www.chapter31.com/2006/12/04/viewing-ajax-generated-source-code/